# OpenGL Rotation Stop/Start Button

Tags: javascript, html, opengl-es, rotation

I need to create a start/stop button to start or stop the animation of a rotating square , I used a loop variable to decide if the square should rotate or not; in the render() function , if loop = 1 the square must rotate , if loop = 0 it stops. At the beginning loop=1 so the square is loaded in the html page rotating but the idea is that if I click the stop button it should stop , but it does not work.

Here is my code :

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<script id="vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">

attribute  vec4 vPosition;
attribute  vec4 vColor;
varying vec4 fColor;

uniform vec3 theta;

void main()
{
    // Compute the sines and cosines of theta for each of
    //   the three axes in one computation.
    vec3 angles = radians( theta );
    vec3 c = cos( angles );
    vec3 s = sin( angles );

    // Remeber: thse matrices are column-major
    mat4 rx = mat4( 1.0,  0.0,  0.0, 0.0,
            0.0,  c.x,  s.x, 0.0,
            0.0, -s.x,  c.x, 0.0,
            0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0 );

    mat4 ry = mat4( c.y, 0.0, -s.y, 0.0,
            0.0, 1.0,  0.0, 0.0,
            s.y, 0.0,  c.y, 0.0,
            0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 1.0 );


    mat4 rz = mat4( c.z, s.z, 0.0, 0.0,
            -s.z,  c.z, 0.0, 0.0,
            0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
            0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );

    fColor = vColor;
    gl_Position = rz * ry * rx * vPosition;
    gl_Position.z = -gl_Position.z;
}
</script>

<script id="fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">

precision mediump float;

varying vec4 fColor;

void
main()
{
    gl_FragColor = fColor;
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../Common/webgl-utils.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Common/initShaders.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Common/MV.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Exercise1_1.js"></script>

<body>
<canvas id="gl-canvas" width="512"" height="512">
Oops ... your browser doesn't support the HTML5 canvas element
</canvas>

<br/>

<button id= "xButton">Rotate X</button>
<button id= "yButton">Rotate Y</button>
<button id= "zButton">Rotate Z</button>
<button id="StopButton">STOP ! </button>

</body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
"use strict";

var canvas;
var gl;
var loop = 1;

var NumVertices  = 36;

var points = [];
var colors = [];

var xAxis = 0;
var yAxis = 1;
var zAxis = 2;


var axis = 0;
var theta = [ 0, 0, 0 ];

var thetaLoc;

window.onload = function init()
{
    canvas = document.getElementById( "gl-canvas" );

    gl = WebGLUtils.setupWebGL( canvas );
    if ( !gl ) { alert( "WebGL isn't available" ); }

    colorCube();

    gl.viewport( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
    gl.clearColor( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 );

    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

    //
    //  Load shaders and initialize attribute buffers
    //
    var program = initShaders( gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader" );
    gl.useProgram( program );

    var cBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cBuffer );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(colors), gl.STATIC_DRAW );

    var vColor = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vColor" );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( vColor, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vColor );

    var vBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vBuffer );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(points), gl.STATIC_DRAW );


    var vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vPosition" );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( vPosition, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vPosition );

    thetaLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "theta");

    //event listeners for buttons

    document.getElementById( "xButton" ).onclick = function () {
        axis = xAxis;
    };
    document.getElementById( "yButton" ).onclick = function () {
        axis = yAxis;
    };
    document.getElementById( "zButton" ).onclick = function () {
        axis = zAxis;
    };

    document.getElementById("StopButton").onclick = function () {
        loop = 0;
    };




    render();
}

function colorCube()
{
    quad( 1, 0, 3, 2 );
    quad( 2, 3, 7, 6 );
    quad( 3, 0, 4, 7 );
    quad( 6, 5, 1, 2 );
    quad( 4, 5, 6, 7 );
    quad( 5, 4, 0, 1 );
}

function quad(a, b, c, d)
{
    var vertices = [
        vec4( -0.5, -0.5,  0.5, 1.0 ),
        vec4( -0.5,  0.5,  0.5, 1.0 ),
        vec4(  0.5,  0.5,  0.5, 1.0 ),
        vec4(  0.5, -0.5,  0.5, 1.0 ),
        vec4( -0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 1.0 ),
        vec4( -0.5,  0.5, -0.5, 1.0 ),
        vec4(  0.5,  0.5, -0.5, 1.0 ),
        vec4(  0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 1.0 )
    ];

    var vertexColors = [
        [ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ],  // black
        [ 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ],  // red
        [ 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 ],  // yellow
        [ 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 ],  // green
        [ 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0 ],  // blue
        [ 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0 ],  // magenta
        [ 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 ],  // cyan
        [ 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 ]   // white
    ];

    // We need to parition the quad into two triangles in order for
    // WebGL to be able to render it.  In this case, we create two
    // triangles from the quad indices

    //vertex color assigned by the index of the vertex

    var indices = [ a, b, c, a, c, d ];

    for ( var i = 0; i < indices.length; ++i ) {
        points.push( vertices[indices[i]] );
        //colors.push( vertexColors[indices[i]] );

        // for solid colored faces use
        colors.push(vertexColors[a]);

    }
}

function render()
{
    gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    if (loop = 0) {
        theta[axis] = 0.0;
    }

    else  {
        theta[axis] +=2.0;
    }



    gl.uniform3fv(thetaLoc, theta);

    gl.drawArrays( gl.TRIANGLES, 0, NumVertices );

    requestAnimFrame( render );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change
if (loop = 0)
To
if (loop == 0)

For a comparison in JavaScript you can use == or ===, the second option also checks the type. In your case both options can be used.

You used a single = which is used to assign a value to a variable.

If you want to stop rendering completely, you could rewrite your render function like this:

```
function render()
{
    if (loop == 0) {
        return;
    }

    gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    theta[axis] += 2.0;

    gl.uniform3fv(thetaLoc, theta);

    gl.drawArrays( gl.TRIANGLES, 0, NumVertices );

    requestAnimFrame( render );
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! Now it works but and it stops the square and returns it in the starting position, is it possible to stop it in the position he has when I click the button ?